# How do I link to a tag

Tags: support, status-completed

I would like to reference the "aikido" tag in the wiki entry on "bokken". How do I do that? (within the text of the tag wiki, not below the entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[tag:discussion]
```

Produces:

[discussion](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion)